# Read from file and query the related row from DB which have results more than chunk size and update

Tags: spring-batch

We have to read a flat file and query the related rows in DB(SQL server) which returns results more than the chunk size(2K) which is being set. so we cannot query in the ItemProcessor so moved the querying and updating part to ItemWriter.

In ItemWriter, the querying is done using the JPA Repository method which accepts one string and 2K values for `in clause`.

Sample Query,

```
select * from FOO where key=? and value in (?)
```

The table has 50M records. 
After fetching the rows will do some modification and leave it. Using `@Transactional` to commits when exiting method. All this working fine for "FOO.key" which has 100K in 50M records. but slow for "FOO.KEY" which has 400K in 50M and more. both columns have the index.

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chunk size and the number of returned results for each item are two different things and it makes no sense to compare them.

If you are reading the flat file with a chunk size of 100, and for each item you are doing a query to the db and this query returns 2000 records for the current item, then comparing 2000 and 100 makes no sense. There is no relation between these two numbers.

> so we cannot query in the ItemProcessor so moved the querying and updating part to ItemWriter.
>
> what is wrong here?

Reading in the writer is what is wrong here. The item writer is meant to write data, doing a query in it is not correct. You are basically implementing the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) where items are coming from the flat file and complementary data for each item is coming from the db. So your query should go in the item processor (and not the writer) and your updating part in the item writer.

Comment: you could also chain different readers if you want strictly separate concerns where processors only filter or transform data (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html)